# How to align the heatmap y-ticks in the center on the secondary axis

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, seaborn, heatmap

I have a data frame like this:

```
l1 = ['A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B','B','B','B','B','B','B']
l2 = ['Name-1','Name-2','Name-3','Name-4','Name-5','Name-6','Name-7','Name-8','Name-9','Name-10','Name-11','Name-12','Name-13','Name-14','Name-15','Name-16','Name-17','Name-18','Name-19','Name-20']
v1 = [1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1]
v2 = [0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1]
v3 = [1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0]
v4 = [0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1]
v5 = [1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1]
v6 = [1,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1]
v7 = [0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,1]
v8 = [0,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1]
v9 = [1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1]
v10 =[1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1]
d = {'variable': l1, 'value': l2,'ID1': v1,'ID2': v2,'ID3': v3,'ID4': v4,'ID5': v5,'ID6': v6,'ID7': v7,'ID8': v8,'ID9': v9,'ID10': v10} 
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
df = df.set_index(['variable','value'])

sum_list = df.sum(axis=0)
```

and I created a heatmap with Y-tick labels on the left and right. which looks like this:

```
sns.set(rc={'figure.figsize': (10,10),'xtick.labelsize': 12,'ytick.labelsize': 12, 'axes.labelcolor': 'black',
           'ytick.left': True, 'ytick.right': True,'axes.grid': False,})
heat_map = sns.heatmap(df.reset_index(level='variable', col_level=0,drop=True),square=False,yticklabels=True,xticklabels=False,cmap=['#FFFFFF','#ff0303'],vmin=0,vmax=1,cbar=False,linewidths=1,linecolor='black', annot_kws={"fontsize":3})
heat_map.set_yticklabels(labels=heat_map.get_yticklabels(),weight='bold',color='black')
heat_map.set(xlabel=None,ylabel=None)
sec_axis=heat_map.twinx()
sec_axis.set_yticks(heat_map.get_yticks())
sec_axis.set_yticklabels(df.sum(axis=1).values[::-1], weight='bold', color='black', fontsize=12) ## Add tick labels which will be the sum
sec_axis.grid(False)
```

By adding second y-ticklabels(right side), my edges along 4 sides disappeared and yticks on the right side are not aligned in the center. I want to:

1. **Display the heatmap along with edges visible**
2. **Center-align the yticks on the secondary y-axis**

This is how my heatmap looks:
[image]

Comment: All you need is to add `sec_axis.set_ylim(heat_map.get_ylim())` after creating `sec_axis` and then `sec_axis.set_yticks(heat_map.get_yticks(), df.sum(axis=1), weight='bold', color='black', fontsize=12)` see [code and plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ef5Ym.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a secondary axis using `tiwnx()`. Get the sum of values of each row using `df.sum(axis=1).values[::-1]` so that the sum is set in the right order and then use `set_yticklabels()` show the same. Add the below code to your existing code.

```
sec_axis=heat_map.twinx() ##sec_axis in the secondary axis (y axis on right)
sec_axis.set_yticks(heat_map.get_yticks()) ## Use same ticks as the primary axis
sec_axis.set_yticklabels(df.sum(axis=1).values[::-1], weight='bold', color='black', fontsize=12) ## Add tick labels which will be the sum
sec_axis.grid(False) ## Remove any grid lines for secondary axis if present
```

**NEW REQ**

I have updated the code to adjust the secondary y-ticks. Looks like the edge lines were not present in your original plot or request. Anyway, added the code for that as well.

- To adjust the y-ticks, use get_ylim() and adjust it so that this adjusts to the primary y-ticks and use set_major_locator() to set the secondary y-axis()
- splines should have worked, but seems like this is not showing. Used axhline and and axvline in its place.

```
l1 = ['A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B','B','B','B','B','B','B']
l2 = ['Name-1','Name-2','Name-3','Name-4','Name-5','Name-6','Name-7','Name-8','Name-9','Name-10','Name-11','Name-12','Name-13','Name-14','Name-15','Name-16','Name-17','Name-18','Name-19','Name-20']
v1 = [1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1]
v2 = [0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1]
v3 = [1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0]
v4 = [0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1]
v5 = [1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1]
v6 = [1,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1]
v7 = [0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,1]
v8 = [0,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1]
v9 = [1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1]
v10 =[1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1]
d = {'variable': l1, 'value': l2,'ID1': v1,'ID2': v2,'ID3': v3,'ID4': v4,'ID5': v5,'ID6': v6,'ID7': v7,'ID8': v8,'ID9': v9,'ID10': v10} 
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
df = df.set_index(['variable','value'])
sum_list = df.sum(axis=0)
sns.set(rc={'figure.figsize': (10,10),'xtick.labelsize': 12, 'ytick.labelsize': 12, 'axes.labelcolor': 'black', 'ytick.left': True, 'ytick.right': True})

heat_map = sns.heatmap(df.reset_index(level='variable', col_level=0, drop=True),square=False,yticklabels=True, xticklabels=False,cmap=['#FFFFFF','#ff0303'], vmin=0,vmax=1,cbar=False,linewidths=1, linecolor='black', annot_kws={"fontsize":3})
heat_map.set_yticklabels(labels=heat_map.get_yticklabels(),weight='bold',color='black')

sec_axis=heat_map.twinx()

import matplotlib.ticker
l = heat_map.get_ylim()
l2 = sec_axis.get_ylim()
f = lambda x : l2[0]+(x-l[0])/(l[1]-l[0])*(l2[1]-l2[0])
ticks = f(heat_map.get_yticks())
sec_axis.yaxis.set_major_locator(matplotlib.ticker.FixedLocator(ticks))

sec_axis.set_yticklabels(df.sum(axis=1).values, ha="center", weight='bold', color='black', fontsize=12, va="center")
sec_axis.grid(False)

heat_map.axhline(y = 0, color = 'k', linewidth = 5)
heat_map.axhline(y = 20, color = 'k', linewidth = 5)
heat_map.axvline(x = 0, color = 'k', linewidth = 5)
heat_map.axvline(x = 20, color = 'k', linewidth = 5)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Redox. I am able to Add the yticklabels on the right side but now: 
1. Edges along all sides of the graph is not visible 
2. new yticks(Right side) are not aligned in the center while the old yticks(Left side) are properly aligned.

Many Thanks

Can you help me with this?

Comment: Check under new req section of response